# Prove that this group is an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, abelian-groups

I'm trying to prove this but can't find the way.

[image]

What I think about is this: "We want to prove that $ab=ba$, i.e. if $aa=e$ , $a=a'$ where $a'$ is the inverse and $bb=e$, $b=b'$ where $b'$ is the inverse so $ab=(ab)'=b'a'=ba...$ but this is by definition. I can't reach the point how does it changes based on prime numbers.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have not asked the question properly.

Comment: Yikes. That exercise is badly written. Also for future reference, please type your question using MathJax rather than insert an image, to prevent issues like broken links from cropping up in the future. Additionally you'll get a better response if you show what you've tried. MathJax help located here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/90543

Comment: What is $n$ and what is $\otimes_p$?

Comment: Can restate the question ?

Answer (score 1):

For prime $p$, $\mathbb Z_p^×$ is cyclic...  ($\therefore$ abelian)

It is also written $\mathbb Z_p^*$, since it is the multiplicative group of nonzero elements of the field $\mathbb Z_p$

In fact, $\mathbb Z_n^×$(the multiplicative group of *units* in $\mathbb Z_n$) is cyclic for $n=1,2,4$, a power of an odd prime or twice a power of an odd prime...  (as Gauss knew, i believe...)